# Configuration properties bean is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Имеется запись, наподобии следующей, завязанная на `application.yml` при помощи аннотации `@EnableConfigurationProperties({AppProperties.class})` в основном классе моего Spring Boot приложения.

```java
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties("converter")
public record AppProperties(/* properties */) {

    public record TableConfig(/* properties */) {
        //
    }
}
```

Так же имеется валидирующий эту запись класс, выглядящий примерно так:

```
@Component(EnableConfigurationProperties.VALIDATOR_BEAN_NAME)
public class AppPropertiesValidator implements Validator {
    // code skipped
}
```

Во время запуска данного Spring Boot приложения в логах появляется следующее предупреждение:

```
2023-09-07T06:54:55.191+03:00  INFO 328 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesValidator' of type [x.x.x.config.AppPropertiesValidator] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

Как это исправить? Я прочитал [**вот эту**](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-not-eligible-for-auto-proxying) статью на baeldung.com но не смог понять как исправить данную проблему в моём случае. Добавление аннотации `@Lazy` в `AppProperties` или в `AppPropertiesValidator` проблему не решает.

P.S. Spring Boot 3.1.3, Java 17.